# Неожиданно перестала работать регулярное выражение, в чём проблема?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражения работало, но не пойму после чего стало ругаться: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот часть кода:

```
function validateUser(user){
    // regExp выражения
    let templateFullName = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$|^([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)$/;
    let templateLoginAndPassword = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;
    let templateEmail = /^[\w_.]{3,}@([a-z]{2,})\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

    let divWithErrors = document.getElementById("divWithErrors");
    let statusOperation = false;

    if(templateFullName.test(user.name) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Name error";
    }else if (templateFullName.test(user.middleName) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Error in middle name";
    }else if (templateFullName.test(user.lastName) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Last name error";
    }else if (templateLoginAndPassword.test(user.login) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Error in login";
    }else if (templateLoginAndPassword.test(user.password) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Error in password";
    }else if (user.password != user.repeatPassword){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Passwords aren't the same";
    }else if (templateEmail.test(user.email) != true){
        divWithErrors.innerText = "Error in email";
    }else{
        statusOperation = true;
        divWithErrors.innerText = "";
    }

    return statusOperation;
}
```

Ругается на строчку: let templateFullName = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$|^([а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)$/;

Comment: А в какой кодировке у вас скрипт ? что то в сообщении об ошибке какая абракадабра. А раз неправильно определена кодировка, то и конечно диапазоны символов могут быть некорректны

Comment: Везде ставлю UTF-8

Comment: На html странице: <meta charset="utf-8">
Подключение скрипта: <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="js/registration.js"></script>

Comment: Это написано для браузера, что UTF8. но в какой кодировке реально текст. У вас редактор на какую кодировку выставлен, когда вы видите нормальные русские буквы

Comment: Есть в настройках параметр Text Editor -> Files -> Encoding, там установлен utf8.
Открываю все файлы в Notepad++ там везде кодировка UTF-8.
Возможно ли, что влияет Tomcat сервер? на котором запускается мой web проект Java ?

Comment: А причем тут java, js файл же должен отдается клиенту как есть. Вряд ли сервер будет менять кодировку при передаче. Кстати регуляка скопированная как есть из примера в консоли хрома ошибок не дает. Но что бы это ни значило очень похоже, что браузер получает файл с испорченной кодировкой. При передаче js на клиента что то его перекодирует

Comment: Спасибо большое! Думаю знаю где поискать ошибку, надеюсь получится

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняйте ваши файлы в кодировке UTF8 и проследите, чтобы при передаче файла не происходило повторное кодирование (у вас произошло двойное кодирование в UTF8).

Кроме того, можно использовать запись в виде кодов Юникода:

```
let templateFullName = /^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[\u0430-\u044F\u0410-\u042F\u0451\u0401]+)$/
```

где `\u0430-\u044F` - `а-я`, `\u0410-\u042F` — `А-Я`, `\u0451` — `ё` и `\u0401` — `Ё`.